# How to handle a null reference exception inside html helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and I have the following viewModel:-

```
public class ServerJoin
    {
        public TMSServer Server { get; set; }
        public Resource Resource { get; set; }
        public Technology Technology { get; set; }
        public ComponentDefinition ComponentDefinition { get; set; }
        public SDOrganization Site { get; set; }
        public SDOrganization Customer { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<NetworkInfo> NetworkInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

On the _createANDupdate view that is used to  edit and create new ServerJoin object I have the following:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.ServerJoin

<span class="f">IP Address</span> 

    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS) | 
    @Html.CheckBox("IsIPUnique",new  { @checked = "checked" } ) IP Unique. 

</div>
```

But the problem I am facing is that the `NetworkInfo` is a collection so I am unable to directly access its `IPADDRESS` property. And in case I wrote the following foreach:-

```
@foreach(var n in Model.NetworkInfo)
```

I will get the null reference exception

> Object reference not set to an instance of an objec

So how I can solve this issue and have the following:-

1. In case I am inside an edit view, I should display all IPaddress(1 editorfor, 2 editorfor, etc).
2. In case I am inside the create view, I should create only one ip editorfor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@If(Model.NetworkInfo!=null)
{
   Html.EditorFor(model=>model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS)
   Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS) | 
   Html.CheckBox("IsIPUnique",new  { @checked = "checked" } ) IP Unique.

}
else
{
    foreach(var n in Model.NetworkInfo)
    {
       ......
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am not sure what do u mean by doing a forach if the Model.NetworkInfo == null.

Answer (score -1):

Something like that:

```
@If(Model.NetworkInfo.Count() == 0)
{
   Html.EditorFor(model=>model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS)
   Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.NetworkInfo.IPADDRESS) | 
   Html.CheckBox("IsIPUnique",new  { @checked = "checked" } ) IP Unique.

}
else
{
    foreach(var n in Model.NetworkInfo)
    {
       ......
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but Model.NetworkInfo.Count() will raise a null reference exception, in case i am adding a new ServerJoin !!!